# How to sets of data in a text file separated by blank lines

Tags: java

I have a text file containing meal recipes where each recipe is separated by a blank line. The recipe consists of the name, time to cook the recipe and ingredients all on a separate line. Following th=is is a blank line and then the next recipe will follow.

I have created a Recipe class to store each recipe and a Recipe Manager class to then store all recipes in a list and will also contain various methods to search for recipes based on field like ingredient.

I have a method to read the first recipe before the first blank line to then place the data in a temporary list and then use this to create the Recipe object for the recipe and then store it in the RecipeManager object that will hold the list of recipes. I would need to read the recipes from the txt file (separated by a blank line) one at a time, and that is where I would need some help and guidance. Below is the txt file and the relevant class file.

Recipes.txt :

```
Pancake dough
60
milk
egg
flour
sugar
salt
butter

Meatballs
20
ground meat
egg
breadcrumbs

Tofu rolls
30
tofu
rice
water
carrot
cucumber
avocado
wasabi
```

UserInterface.java

```
public class UserInterface {
    private Scanner scanner;
    private RecipesManager manager; //object to hold list of recipes with access to varous methods to search for recipes

    public UserInterface(Scanner scanner, RecipesManager manager) {
        this.scanner = scanner;
        this.manager = manager;
    }
    
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("File to read: ");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Commands: ");
        System.out.println("list - lists the recipes");
        System.out.println("stop - stops the program");
        readFile(input);
        
    }
    
    private void readFile(String fileName){ //method to read the recipes from the text file
        ArrayList<String> recipe = new ArrayList<>(); //List to store recipe that is to be read
        try {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(Paths.get(fileName));
            while(file.hasNext()){
                String line = file.nextLine();
                recipe.add(line);
            }
            createRecipe(recipe);
            System.out.println(recipe);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        } //currently reads all the lines in the text file but need it to read one recipe at a time 
    }
    
    private void createRecipe(ArrayList<String> recipe){ //method to create recipe object and then store in a list of recipes (RecipeManager)
        String name = recipe.get(0);
        int time = Integer.valueOf(recipe.get(1)); //convert the time in String format to Integer
        ArrayList<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<>(); //list of ingredients
        for(int i=2; i<recipe.size(); i++){ //add ingredients found from index 2 onwards, to the ingredients list
            ingredients.add(recipe.get(i));
        }
        
        manager.addRecipe(new Recipe(name, time, ingredients)); //add to the list of recipes in the RecipeManager object
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _I would need to read the recipes from the txt file one at a time_ ?Currently you read the first recipe in `readFile` method. Do you need to read all recipes there in an outer loop (until end of file is reached)?  Or you need to call `readFile` several times and read the next recipe in each invocation?

Comment: @AlexRudenko It currently reads all lines in the txt file and adds it to the `recipe` list. What I wanted is for it to read the lines until the blank line, and then get to `createRecipe(recipe);` where it will then create a Recipe object for that recipe. Then continue to read the recipe after the blank line until the next blank line until there are no more recipes left.

Comment: Hint: use readLine and look for empty lines to determine when you are done adding ingredients to a recipe.